# Restrict the views in the inline Lookup for a subgrid

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

There is an N:N relationship between Opportunity entity and Competitor entity.

In Opportunity, there is a subgrid for competitor. When I click the '+' button, I get an inline lookup.

My requirement is to restrict the view of this lookup to 1 view. Even when I select "Look for more records", I want the user to select the records from only 1 view. He should not be able to change the view.

I know how to filter records for a lookup. I am getting some unsupported ways to filter records for a subgrid. Is there a supported way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to achieve your requirement. Very unfortunate.

[Unsupported solution](http://missdynamicscrm.blogspot.com/2016/05/filter-n-to-n-many-to-many-subgrid-lookup-existing-record-form-script.html?m=1): (if anybody looking for)